# Handling OnClick on an item within a RecyclerView element?

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview of cardviews, and each cardview has a thumbs-up (like) button.

I would like it so that when a user clicks the thumb button on a particular card, they "like" that post, the button animates and the appropriate logic is handled.

Here is my code so far:

```
 private class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private CardView mCardView;
    private TextView cardTitle, cardUsername;
    private ImageView cardImage;
    public CardViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        cardTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle);
        cardUsername = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardUsername);
        cardImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
        mLikeButton = (LikeButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mLikeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == mLikeButton.getId()){
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ROW PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mRecipes[getAdapterPosition()].getRecipename().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks the like button, it does display the correct adapter position in the toast, but it does not animate like it should and I have no way of setting the animation on it. Ordinarily, the button animates when clicked, but when it's within the recyclerview it does not seem to work.

I tried to do

```
(LikeButton) v.setLiked(true);
```

but the cast didn't seem to work. I want to be able to get a direct reference to the specific like button in a specific row of the recyclerview so that I may call a method on it. Is that possible?

Is this a bad way of setting the click listener on the button?

Comment: Set on click listener in onBindViewHolder method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies at the view id check. If you want to go with your solution this would be the way:

```
private static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements View.OnClickListener {

private CardView mCardView;
private TextView cardTitle, cardUsername;
private ImageView cardImage;

public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
    cardTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle);
    cardUsername = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardUsername);
    cardImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
    mLikeButton = (LikeButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    mLikeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v instanceof LikeButton) {
        // You now this is the LikeButton
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " +
                String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ((LikeButton) v).setLiked(true);
    } else {
        // Not a LikeButton
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ROW PRESSED = " +
                String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                mRecipes[getAdapterPosition()].getRecipename().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

What we do here is to check if the `View` is a `LikeButton`. If so, we can safely cast it and call our method on it. If not it is a `itemView`. 
A better way in my opinion would be, to anonymiously implement the `OnClickListener`s. This would look like this:

```
private static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements View.OnClickListener {

private CardView mCardView;
private TextView cardTitle, cardUsername;
private ImageView cardImage;

public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
    cardTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle);
    cardUsername = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardUsername);
    cardImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
    mLikeButton = (LikeButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // You now for sure this is an ItemView.
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ROW PRESSED = " +
                    String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                    mRecipes[getAdapterPosition()].getRecipename().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mLikeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // You now for sure this is a LikeButton.
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " +
                    String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            ((LikeButton) v).setLiked(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here we have an `OnClickListener` for each `View` we want to handle. Because every `View` has it's own, we always know which `View` has been clicked and can act accordingly.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much, mate!